# Using Gmail Addons inside Inbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I don't find how to use Gmail addons inside Inbox:

https://inbox.gmail.com

Is it not supported?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/) says:

> The contextual cards you create for your add-ons work for both web and mobile 
>   versions of Gmail.

---

Sidenote: Gmail addons are not supported on *mobile version* of the website https://mail.google.com, not supported in the iOS Gmail app, seems not supported in Inbox. Are Gmail addons in decline (so not worth spending time developing one) or just in its infancy (that's why it's not supported on all platforms *yet*)?

Comment: I'd say Gmail add-ons are just in their infancy. The feature was released in the latter part of 2017 so its not even a year old as of this writing. May need to give the platform more time to mature.

Comment: Release notes for Gmail Add-ons: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2017#october_24_2017 Blog post: https://www.blog.google/products/g-suite/do-more-your-inbox-gmail-add-ons/ Devblog: https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/gmail-add-ons-framework-now-available.html